# How to create multi-release jar and filtering input content?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, java-9

I would like to create multi-release jar (for Java 8 and Java 9) by `jar` command.
There are several Netbeans IDE projects: com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8, com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9. 
Projects source code is [here](https://github.com/java1cprog/java-9-revealed/tree/master/Java9Revealed).
Using command line I go to a parent folder and run command.
When I try to do this:

```
jar --create --file mrjars/com.jdojo.mrjar.jar
    -C com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes .
    --release 9 -C com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/build/classes .
```

I get a message:

```
Warning: entry META-INF/versions/9/.netbeans_automatic_build contains a class that
is identical to an entry already in the jar
Warning: entry META-INF/versions/9/.netbeans_update_resources contains a class that
is identical to an entry already in the jar
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:384)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:288)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1413)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.validateAndClose(Main.java:460)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:343)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1670)
```

I think this is due to the presence of the development environment service files. Is there any possibility of filtering them (select only the files of a certain file type for packing them by jar)?

---

The jar operations described in [Java Platform, Standard Edition Tools Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jar.htm#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867__GUID-44BCC07B-1A03-4FEE-884B-EF057B22299F).

Comment: Have you tried listing the `class` files explicitly instead of using `-C`? That way you can see whether excluding the `.netbeans...` folders helps. Also, interesting that these are only warnings so maybe unrelated to the exception. Is there no cause in there?

Comment: Yes, @Nicolai . The list of `class` files is solved filtering problem. I think `$(find -name *.class)` command will be useful for this. But there are other problems it is for this way. There is no way to specify where is a root folder of the list of the source code files.

Comment: Therefore, erroneous packing of files occurs (`com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9.build.classes.com.jdojo.mrjar`).

Comment: More precisely, the packaging does not happen: 

`jar --create --file com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/dist/com.jdojo.mrjar.jar $(find com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes -name *.class) --release 9 $(find com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/build/classes -name *.class)`
 
`...
invalid multi-release jar file com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/dist/com.jdojo.mrjar.jar deleted`

Comment: `.netbeans_automatic_build` and `.netbeans_update_resources` are files.

Comment: I think that throwing `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` exeption and warning messages have indirect relation.

Comment: I never tried it but I think you can use `-C` to inform `jar` of the root folder for the binary files _and then_ enumerate them explicitly instead of using `.`. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes. `-C` option  inform `jar` about the root folder but unfortunately it is not help filtering files.

Comment: I meant something like `jar --create --file ... -C com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes $(find com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes -name *.class) --release ...` This way you might be able to set the root _and_ then filter files yourself. This should at least get rid of the erroneous packing of files as `com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9.build.classes.com.jdojo.mrjar`.

Comment: Ok. This is full command listing of it: `jar --create --file mrjars/com.jdojo.mrjar.jar -C com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes $(find com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes -name *.class)  --release 9 $(find com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/build/classes -name *.class)`.
This is the message I get: `com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8\build\classes\com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8\build\classes\com\jdojo\mrjar\Main.class : no such file or directory`. Sequence of commands helps to solve my question I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There is the shortest full sequence of commands:*

```
cd com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes && jar -c -f com.jdojo.mrjar.jar $(find -name *.class) && cd ../../.. && mv -f com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes/com.jdojo.mrjar.jar -t com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/build/classes  && cd com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/build/classes  && jar -u -f com.jdojo.mrjar.jar --release 9 $(find -name *.class) && cd ../../.. && mv -f com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/build/classes/com.jdojo.mrjar.jar -t com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/mrjars
```

*Step-by-step description of the execution of commands*

1. go to "com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes" folder: 
    `cd com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes`
2. run jar command in this place: 
     `jar -c -f com.jdojo.mrjar.jar $(find -name *.class)`
3. go back:  
     `cd ../../..`
4. move created jar file to an other folder:  
    `mv -f com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8/build/classes/com.jdojo.mrjar.jar -t com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/build/classes`
5. go to this folder:  
     `cd com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/build/classes`
6. updating moved jar file:  
     `jar -u -f com.jdojo.mrjar.jar --release 9 $(find -name *.class)`
7. go back:  
    `cd ../../..`
8. moving updated jar file to destination folder:  
    `mv -f com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/build/classes/com.jdojo.mrjar.jar -t com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9/mrjars`

Perhaps, there may be a shorter solution.