# Issue creating Mrjar

Tags: java, jar, java-9

I am trying to create a multi release jar in windows 10 using two projects built with Netbeans. The projects are the same, only difference is one has jdk8 under properties > sources/libraries and the other has jdk9.
They both have a *com.jdojo.mrjar* package and under it they both have a TimeUtil class

```
public class TimeUtil {
    public TimeUtil() {
        System.out.println("Creating JDK 8 version of TimeUtil...");
    }
    public LocalDate getLocalDate(Instant now){
        return now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

And a simple main class to call it

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Inside JDK 8 version of Main.main([])...");
        TimeUtil t = new TimeUtil();
        LocalDate ld = t.getLocalDate(Instant.now());
        System.out.println("Local Date: "+ld);
    }
}
```

The jdk9 version has also a `module-info.java`:

```
module com.jdojo.mrjar {
    exports com.jdojo.mrjar;
}
```

They both compile and run properly but when i try the command 
**jar --create --file mrjars\com.jdojo.mrjar.jar -C com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk8\build\classes . --release 9 -C com.jdojo.mrjar.jdk9\build\classes .** I have the following error :

```
Warning: entry META-INF/versions/9/.netbeans_automatic_build contains a class that
is identical to an entry already in the jar
Warning: entry META-INF/versions/9/.netbeans_update_resources contains a class that
is identical to an entry already in the jar
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Talon\AppData\Local\Temp\com.jdojo.mrjar.jar15612736007782051855.jar -> mrjars\com.jdojo.mrjar.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:384)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:288)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1413)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.validateAndClose(Main.java:460)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:343)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1670)
```

As of [How to create multi-release jar and filtering input content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500592/how-to-create-multi-release-jar-and-filtering-input-content), if i try the suggested solution i have

```
$(find : no such file or directory
-name : no such file or directory
*.class) : no such file or directory
```

So i've simply removed the `.netbeans_automatic_build` and `.netbeans_update_resources` files from the folders since they seemed to be the cause of the problem, if i try the command now i have a different error

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Talon\AppData\Local\Temp\com.jdojo.mrjar.jar12504656669179695067.jar -> mrjars\com.jdojo.mrjar.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:384)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:288)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1413)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.validateAndClose(Main.java:460)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:343)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1670)
```

I've checked the folder and yes `com.jdojo.mrjar.jar12504656669179695067.jar` is not there, the question is why it should be ?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45500592/2525313)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multi-release jar and filtering input content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500592/how-to-create-multi-release-jar-and-filtering-input-content)

Comment: I've edited the post, if i work around that i have a different error.